# How to solve 404 on Retrofit @POST on Django RESTful API?

Tags: java, android, django-rest-framework, retrofit

I am able to get data from database using retrofit and REST api but facing errors in Posting data. Post works using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)  but not through [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).I have been unable to locate the error.I have tried changing endpoint, that is, "rest" and "rest/" but still get not found error.

ApiView of Post in Django RESTful api: view.py

```
def post(self,request):
    serializer =table_restSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'results':serializer.data},status=201)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=404)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^rest',views.restSerializer.as_view())
    ]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

serializer.py:

```
class table_restSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = table_rest
        fields = '__all__'
```

My android code: 
Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("rest")
    Call<CustomViewResponse> getJsonFromSid();

    @POST("rest")
    Call<CustomViewResponse> createTask(@Body CustomViewHolder task);
}
```

CustomViewHolder class:

```
public class CustomViewHolder {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("tt")
    private String tt;

    @SerializedName("varr")
    private Integer varr;

    @SerializedName("edi")
    private String edi;
    public CustomViewHolder(String tt, Integer varr, String edi){
        this.tt = tt;
        this.varr = varr;
        this.edi = edi;
    }

    public Integer getid(){
        return id;
    }
    /*public void setid(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }*/

    public String gettt()
    {
        return tt;
    }
    public void settt(String tt){
        this.tt = tt;
    }

    public Integer getvarr(){
        return varr;
    }

    public void setvarr(Integer varr){
        this.varr = varr;
    }

    public String getedi(){
        return edi;
    }

    public void setedi(String edi){
        this.edi = edi;
    }
}

CustomViewResponse class
public class CustomViewResponse {

    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<CustomViewHolder> results;

    public List<CustomViewHolder> getResults(){
        return results;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sid_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        ApiInterface apiService1 = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<CustomViewResponse> call = apiService.getJsonFromSid();

         CustomViewHolder cc = new CustomViewHolder("my task title",22,"a string");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CustomViewResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CustomViewResponse> call, Response<CustomViewResponse> response) {
                int statuscode = response.code();
                List<CustomViewHolder> customViewHolders = response.body().getResults();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterSid(customViewHolders, R.layout.list_item_sid, getApplicationContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CustomViewResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG main", t.toString());
            }
        });
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<CustomViewResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CustomViewResponse> call1, Response<CustomViewResponse> respo) {
                int statuscode = respo.code();
                Log.d("Message", "code..."+respo.code() + " message..." + respo.message());

                CustomViewResponse respon = respo.body();

                if (respon == null){
                    Log.e("Error",""+statuscode+ "......"+ respo.message()+"....null body");
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CustomViewResponse> call1, Throwable t) {

                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Following is my table structure:

```
class table_rest(models.Model):

    tt = models.CharField(max_length=10,default = 12)
    varr = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    edi = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default='44')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tt
```

Using postman my Json body which gets successfully saved is :

```
{
    "tt": "hello",
    "varr": 911,
    "edi": "emergency. Can't find solution"
}
```

Comment: You must know the meanings of response code of RESTful services. 404 means the page you're trying to access doesn't exist

Comment: I know this but for postman I use url "http://192.168.1.50:80/rest" and in android my base url is "http://192.168.1.50:80/". so why am I encountering 404. For get my url is the same "http://192.168.1.50:80/rest" and that does not give me any issues.

Comment: I think the line "serializer.is_valid()" is returning  false in rest api but I don't understand the reason for it.

Comment: try to debug by print `request.data` in post() method. may be, your request data is not valid in retrofit case. @Sid

Answer (score 0):

Please add an extra URL.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), # Any URL starting with admin(ex: http://testdomainname.com/admin/xyz)
    url(r'^rest/$',views.restSerializer.as_view()), # Any URL starting with only rest(ex: http://testdomainname.com/rest/)
    url(r'^$',views.restSerializer.as_view()), # Any empty URL with '' (ex: http://testdomainname.com/)
]
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but am still getting the 404 error.

Comment: Along with the url changes I made more changes and have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I included the url pattern as suggested by Dinesh Mandepudi. Then I made changes to my regex in retrofit. It was url issue that I was not confronting when using postman. I just added '/' at the beginning of my post regex.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/rest")
    Call<CustomViewResponse> getJsonFromSid();

    @POST("/rest/")
    Call<CustomViewResponse> createTask(@Body CustomViewHolder task);
}
```

Also a silly mistake is I was trying to add a string of 13 length in the database column while I had set the limit to 10.